# Документация msdn winapi с++

Tags: c++, winapi

К примеру вот ссылка к документации [Button](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/buttons) в нем есть такое поле как макросы, у меня вопрос как с ними работать?

Comment: Чем их описание из документации не устраивает? А вообще они не нужны, лучше использовать нормальные обертки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и работать, как написано в документации.

К примеру, возьмем макрос Button_SetText, его синтаксис выглядит так:

```
void Button_SetText(
   hwndCtl,
   lpsz
);
```

`hwndCtl` - HWND handle нашей кнопки

`lpsz` - LPTSTR строка, на которую меняем название кнопки

А дальше просто подключаем нужные заголовки и вызываем, необходимый заголовок написан внизу [страницы описания макроса](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-button_settext).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

const LPCWSTR g_szClassName = L"myWindowClass";
HWND btn;
#define BUTTON_ID 3000

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) 
        {
        case BUTTON_ID:
            Button_SetText(btn, L"Changed");
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        L"The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 600,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    btn = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"My Button", BS_PUSHBUTTON |
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 70, 45, 240, 20, hwnd,
        (HMENU)BUTTON_ID, hInstance, NULL
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вместо того, чтобы производить вызов `SendMessage` или `PostMessage` с указанием адресата и некого сообщения, можно произвести вызов  соответствующего сообщению макроса. Например,

```
Button_SetCheck(butt_Handle, BST_CHECKED);
```

действует подобно

```
SendMessage(butt_Handle, BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED, 0);
```

Другие макросы вызывают соответствующие функции (или набор функций) WinAPI:

```
Button_SetText == SetWindowText
```